# Showing argument form is valid by rule of inference

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I seek help in understanding why the method of rule of inference proves that an argument form is valid at a basic level.

Example of an argument

a. $u \lor w$

b. $\neg w$

c. $u \rightarrow p$

$\therefore p$

We start with

(1) : $u\lor w$  (from a)

$\neg w$ (from b)

$\therefore u$

(2) : $u\rightarrow p$ (from c)

$u$ (from (1))

$\therefore p$

Then we conclude that the argument is valid.

In part (1) we have a conclusion, then we used the conclusion (1) in part (2). Why can we do it such a way and always have that the argument is valid?

$\color{blue}{\text{My guess :}}$ In the case that the propositions $u\lor w, \neg w$ and $u\rightarrow p$ are true, $u$ is also true.

So "including" $u$ to our list of propositions, we see that when $u\lor w, \neg w, u\rightarrow p \color{red}{\text{ and }u}$ are true, $p$ is also true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simply because the deductive rules are sound, namely every sentence you write down is true **if** the premises or assumptions governing it are all true.

Here you have the premises $a,b,c$. The first argument shows that if $a,b$ are true then $u$ is true. The second argument shows that if $c,u$ are true then $p$ is true. Combining both arguments shows that if $a,b,c$ are all true then $p$ is true. Hence the argument is a valid one (if all the premises are true then the conclusion is true).